# Laravel8 blade.php can't access or find css file

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-8

Im writing something to welcome.blade.php and want to use css to change the background but it doesnt works.(my css file is in the public folder)here is my blade.php codes;

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" >        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        </head>
<body>
    <p>adddd</p>

    </body>
</html>

and my css codes;

body{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the file exists in the css folder in your public folder? if the file is just in the public folder you will have to remove the "css/" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file structure should like this.

Please check your css file is in public directory or not. If your app.css is inside public/css folder then you need to import as like you already imported in blade file.

Your `welcome.blade.php`

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>adddd</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And for css/app.css
check is there file exists or not in this path => `public/css/app.css`

if not exists then create a file with this directory structure `public/css/app.css` and put your css code inside this file.

```
body{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Hi, your explanation works but say I want all my CSS files in the `resources/css/` location. How would I do this? I don't want my CSS to be in public folder

Comment: From the resource folder you can you resource_path() helper function instead of the asset() helper function.

Answer (score 0):

All css files go in the public/css folder you can then add a blade link like so

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">

Answer (score 0):

In laravel all common assets files like css, js, image, etc  files should be in the public folder
Put your style.css file inside the public folder location like

> your_project_folder/public/css/style.css

then add this line inside the  head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" >
```

Answer (score -2):

all css files go in the resources/css folder you can then add a blade link like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```